# OSX: kernel.log is GB in size

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, logging

Recently, I've started to run out of space on my startup disk.  I used [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) to identify large files that could be removed.  It seems that the kernel*.log files have become GB in size (one was 60GB+).

To fix the problem, I delete the files, restart (to release locks), then empty the trash.

Is this a normal behavior for these log files?  Is there anything that I can do to prevent these from becoming so large?  Might their size be associated with certain types of usage (e.g. VPN)?

** edit 0 **

There are a number of files that follow this pattern: kernel.log[.0-5][.bz2].  They are ~20MB in size.  Apparently, this issue is period and difficult to reproduce.

** edit 1 **

I upgraded my OS to Lion.  We'll see if this addresses the problem.  I'll post the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded Lion; problem solved.  Now on Mountain Lion; problem has not resurfaced.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, my no. Logfiles in OSX (and Unix in general) are usually [rotated](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/courses/apache/html/x1670.htm) (that is, moved into another file and compressed, then later deleted) with [`newsyslog`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=newsyslog&sektion=8). OSX should do this every half an hour.

Either your kernel just did a lot of stuff in the past half hour or your log rotation is broken.

Comment: How would I know which is the case?

Comment: @Craig The easiest (if not the least involved) way is to just look at the file every 5 minutes or so to see if it shrinks.

Comment: Look at the beginning of the log file and see how old the first few entries are.

Comment: That too. (Though you're probably gonna want to use `more` to open a potentially 60gb logfile.)

Comment: @digitxp: how do i fix a broken log rotation?

Comment: @Craig Check whatever the Mac's equivalent of `cron` is (I haven't used one in a while) and see if there's any log rotation services in there.